# github, is it possible for public or google account users to report issues?

Tags: github, public, bug-reporting

Is it in any way possible for public (via captcha?) or with a google login to report issues in Github? Or must they be added as a collaborator and registered on github?

Sorry this seems like a simple question, but as you can imagine googling for things like "github public report issues" is not productive...

This is a related question, but maybe info is out of date? Sounds like the answer was 'go to google code if you want public issue reports' 
[Google Code + SVN or GitHub + Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807782/google-code-svn-or-github-git)

Comment: You can suggest Github team to add openID support. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to be a registered and logged-in GitHub user to report a new issue.